# Reflecting changes on big tables in hdfs

Tags: hdfs, data-warehouse

I have an order table in the OLTP system.
Each order record has a OrderStatus field.

- > When end users created an order, OrderStatus field set as "Open".
- > When somebody cancels the order, OrderStatus field set as "Canceled".
- > When an order process finished(transformed into invoice), OrderStatus field set to "Close".

There are more than one hundred million record in the table in the Oltp system.

I want to design and populate data warehouse and data marts on hdfs layer.
In order to design data marts, I need to import whole order table to hdfs and then I need to reflect changes on the table continuously.

First, I can import whole table into hdfs in the initial load process by using sqoop. I may take long time but I will do this once.

When an order record is updated or a new order record entered, I need to reflect changes in hdfs. How can I achieve this in hdfs for such a big transaction table?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

One of the easier ways is to work with database triggers in your OLTP source db and every change an update happens use that trigger to push an update event to your Hadoop environment.

On the other hand (this depends on the requirements for your data users) it might be enough to reload the whole data dump every night.

Also, if there is some kind of last changed timestamp, it might be a possible way to load only the newest data and do some kind of delta check.

This all depends on your data structure, your requirements and your ressources at hand.

There are several other ways to do this but usually those involve messaging, development and new servers and I suppose in your case this infrastructure or those ressources are not available.

**EDIT**

Since you have a last changed date, you might be able to pull the data with a statement like

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE lastchangedate < (now - 24 hours)
```

or whatever your interval for loading might be.

Then process the data with sqoop or ETL tools or the like. If the records are already available in your Hadoop environment, you want to `UPDATE` it. If the records are not available, `INSERT` them with your appropriate mechanism. This is also called UPSERTING sometimes.

Comment: Yes, there is last changed timestamp field in the source table. Could you give detail over:  "it might be a possible way to load only the newest data and do some kind of delta check."

Comment: Thank you for your comment, is upserting an available option in hadoop environment? As I know hdfs is read only. So I may need to overwrite whole table in hdfs layer,.

Comment: That is just a word for the needed actions. This actually depends on your infrastructure, the components you use and the given requirements. HDFS is not read only, you are already pushing data with Sqoop into it. Changes might create new files, but again: this depends in how you read the data after pushing them into Hadoop. Also, you should look up  components which use HDFS like Hive, HBASE and generally the architecture of Hadoop. HDFS is only a part of the whole ecosphere.